# Return statements are not accepted in the method

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the below method, but the IDE visual studio says not all the code in the method returns value.

I would like to know where the error is.

**Code**:

```
private bool CheckDaysDiff(int daysDiff)
{
    if (daysDiff < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (daysDiff >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (daysDiff == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return daysDiff >= 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you might be satisfied that every path through the method will return a value the compiler doesn't do that level of analysis. IT doesn't look at the conditions so it just sees:  `if (Something) else if (something else) else if (something else)`. What it doesn't see is an else so as far as it is concerned it is possible to get to the end of the method without satisfying any of the conditions and thus without returning anything.

The way to solve this in your case would be to just do:

```
private bool CheckDaysDiff(int daysDiff)
{
    if (daysDiff < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Alternatively if your code is not properly indicative you could just add something before the end of the statement to either return or throw an exception depending on what behaviour you want. If you are confident it should never get to the end of the method then an exception is probably most appropriate (because if it gets there then something exceptional has happened). eg:

```
private bool CheckDaysDiff(int daysDiff)
{
    if (daysDiff < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (daysDiff >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (daysDiff == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    throw new Exception("Should never reach here.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put an else block with return statement in it. Because IDE needs to know what to return if dayDiff is neither < 0 nor = 0 and nor >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be simplified into a one line method using the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
private bool CheckDaysDiff(int daysDiff)
{
    return (daysDiff < 0) ? false : true;
}
```

Like the others have said, the problem with the IDE is because you don't have an ending `else {}` to your conditional, which is partly due to the conditional being overly complex (there's no need to check for both something equaling 0 as well as something that's also equal or greater to 1 if both return true).  Using the ternary operator both simplifies your conditional, and should alleviate the IDE issue.

Comment: Your answer can be simplified as `return daysDiff >= 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `else` statement, that's why IDE says that...

Code update:

```
private bool CheckDaysDiff(int daysDiff)
    {
        if (daysDiff >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (daysDiff == 0)
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```